# Subscribing to a mocked variable in a service unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, service, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a component that subscribes to a data service variable. I'm trying to mock the service and override the component's private data service variable but I'm not sure how to test the subscription of the mocked variable. Here's my (limited) code:

Service:

```
export class Service {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.newData.subscribe(data => {
      //do something
    });
  }
}
```

Data Service:

```
export class DataService {
  private source = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  newData = this.source.asObservable();

  //code to update source
}
```

unit test for Service:

```
mockDataService {
  private source = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  newData = this.source.asObservable();
}

describe('Service', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        Service,
        {provide: DataService, useClass: mockDataService} // is this correct?
      ]
    }).overrideComponent(Service, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          {provide: DataService, useClass: mockDataService}
        ]
      }
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should register subscription', inject([Service, DataService], (service: ServiceA, mock: DataService) => { //should I be injecting the mock class?
    expect(before()).toBeTruthy();
    mock.newData.next("test"); // what's the correct way to test?
    expect(after()).toBeTruthy();
  }));
}
```

Am I overriding correctly? And if so, how do I correctly test that my component does the correct actions when subscribing to a private service's variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, it would be helpful if you could provide the annotations alongside the classes. I am assuming that the `Service` class is a component, because you reference is when calling `TestBed.overrideComponent`. In that case the naming is confusing. It should have at least a suffix "Component" (see Angular [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#symbols-and-file-names).)

If `Service` should actually be a service class, nesting services into another one is probably not a good practice ([see docs](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility).)

---

You are basically asking for two things.

#### 1. Do I need to override the `providers` property of the module via `TestBed.configureTestingModule`?

For your example above, this is not necessary. You can easily omit the providers attribute from the object. It will then looks like

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({})
```

There might be some cases where changing the providers is needed - but not in your case.

#### 2. How should I test the service properly?

It seems like you are mixing up integration testing with unit testing. You want to test the service in both ways.

First: Unit test the service ([Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#services))

Second: Integration test – what you seem to be doing here. There is a recommended best practice as of the docs ([link](https://angular.io/guide/testing#get-injected-services)):

```
it('should register subscription', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Service);
    dataService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
    // do things
});
```

Regarding the `mock.newData.next("test")`, it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve here. This method call would probably give you an `undefined function test` error. Why? You are referring to `this.source.asObservable()` which returns an [Obersvable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). This object does not have a `next` method. You should maybe do some basic tutorials on RxJs.

Hope this helps!

Best,
Benji